# Error on Convert ArrayList to Arrays PayPalItem

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, paypal

I need a Array to PayPal Items must however go another arraylist to add the items as I do that?

```
         ArrayList<PayPalItem[]> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<PayPalItem[]>();

                for (int i=0; i<resultado.size(); i++) {
                    PayPalItem[] items;

                    double x = Math.round(((resultado.get(i).getTotal() / resultado.get(i).getPreco())));
                    int quantidade = (int) x;
                    String preco = String.format("%.2f", resultado.get(i).getPreco());
                    String nome = resultado.get(i).getProduto();

                    items = new PayPalItem[]{
                            new PayPalItem(nome, quantidade, new BigDecimal(resultado.get(i).getPreco()), "BRL",
                                    "dinner")
                    };


                    stringArrayList.add(items); //add to arraylist
                }
                PayPalItem[] items = new PayPalItem[stringArrayList.size()];


                //if you want your array
                PayPalItem[] stringArray = stringArrayList.toArray(items);
```

I'm trying to convert an ArrayList to the Array however I get this error[image]

Comment: why do you create *stringArrayList* as "list of arrays"(ArrayList<PayPalItem[]>)?  I mean, why don't simply create as list of PayItems like ArrayList<PayPalItem>?  For each "resultado" an items array is created with just one element.

Comment: Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion from an arrayList i.e. `ArrayList<Something> list` to an Array is done this way (as you already did):

`list.toArray(Something[])` <- notice that the parameter here is an array of Something elements.

so in your case: Something is PayPalItem[] then you need to add an extra [] because you have an array of arrays.

replacing your last two lines of your code by these two will solve your issue.

```
 PayPalItem[][] items = new PayPalItem[stringArrayList.size()][];
 //if you want your array
 PayPalItem[][] stringArray = stringArrayList.toArray(items);
```

but anyway, I cannot understand why do you need an array of arrays instead of simply just a list or an array. I mean something like this:

```
        ArrayList<PayPalItem> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<PayPalItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            //create the PayPalItem and add to the list                  
            stringArrayList.add(new PayPalItem()); //add to arraylist
        }
        PayPalItem[] items = new PayPalItem[stringArrayList.size()];
        //if you want your array
        PayPalItem[] stringArray = stringArrayList.toArray(items);
```